# Entity Framework Model with inheritance and RIA Services

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

We have an entity framework model with has some inheritance in it.

The following example is not the actuall model, but just to make my point...

Let's say

Base class: Person
Child classes: Employee, Customer

The database has been generated, the DomainService has been created and we can get to the data:

```
lstCustomers.ItemsSource = context.Persons;
EntityQuery<Person> query = context.GetPeopleQuery().Take(4);
context.Load(query);
```

But how can I modify the query to only return Customers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried the following:

```
context.GetPeopleQuery().OfType<Customer>().Take(4)
```

I can imagine this doesn't have the required effect though, because the `OfType` is probably evaluated client-side..

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I'm also wondering where this will execute...  if at all

Comment: Nope the .OfType method is not available

Comment: I found this link
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=RiaServices&DownloadId=8351

I added the .OfType<Customer> to the Domain Service and it works, thank you !

Comment: The above link downloads a Word doc. MSDN has essentially the same info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707366(v=vs.91).aspx